# Can I use JBoss EAP 6 without a support license?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

JBoss Application Platform has 2 distributions, a community and an enterprise release, community releases are like Beta releases of enterprise releases, JBoss 7.0 is then actually EAP 6 beta 1, 7.0.1 is beta 2, 7.1.0 is beta 3 and 7.1.1 is rc 1.

What happens with JBoss AS 7.1.2 and 7.1.3? this is a very informative link: http://henk53.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/the-curious-case-of-jboss-as-7-1-2-and-7-1-3/

So my question is: Can I use JBoss EAP 6 without a support license?

Downloads are available from access.redhat.com/downloads, from which you have to click on "Evaluations and Demos", and then on "JBoss Enterprise Application Platform Evaluation".

I have read that JBoss EAP is still open source and you can use it freely, but only if you compile it from source, which is not an easy task nor they want it to be.

So if I use in production the version I have downloaded from "Evaluations and Demos", is this illegal?

Comment: It's not illegal. I've worked with JBoss EAP 5 in a project and the only cost was the support license (that the client company paid). After that, the sellers told me that I could use the JBoss EAP 5 in personal projects and it's free to distribute. Also, when I took a JBoss Portal Platform course, the professor gave access to every student to get a JBoss Portal Platform 5 distribution (based on JBoss EAP 5) and it was free of charge and we could distribute it (and use it for personal purposes). Note that the products are free but the redhat subscription and product support license have a cost.

Comment: for closers, software tools are on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: **software tools** are ok for Stack Overflow, reopen.

Comment: "but only if you compile it from source, which is not an easy task nor they want it to be." - How hard is it to run mvn? It's even included in the git repo.

Comment: https://github.com/hasalex/eap-build seems pretty neat though.

Comment: Some answers about JBoss AS 7 / EAP 6 can be found in this FAQ : http://jbossas.jboss.org/faq

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TLDR; yes, you can use without a support subscription, but no, if you just download the latest EAP binary, you're not allowed to use it in production.

Three cases here to consider how you can run JBoss EAP without a support subscription, two of which also allow production use:

**1. Development use**

You can use any JBoss EAP *binary version* for development purposes without a paid subscription. You won't get patches or support that way, and you can't run it in production. From ["Downloads for Development Use"](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap/download/):

> To download JBoss EAP you must have an account. You also need to
>   accept the terms and conditions of the JBoss Developer Program which
>   provides $0 subscriptions for development use only.

**2. EAP 6.x alpha versions**

All alpha versions, such as JBoss EAP 6.1 Alpha, are free to use in any way or form, *also in production*. From [this message](https://developer.jboss.org/message/819862#819862):

> The 6.1 Alpha binary is made available for free (both for development
>   and production use) to the entire community.

And [this thread](https://developer.jboss.org/message/819862):

> This development restriction, however, does not apply to EAP alpha
>   releases. EAP alpha releases may be ran in production if you so
>   desire. As to their quality, 6.1.0.Alpha is of equivalent quality to a
>   community final release. However, the Alpha is where the extensive
>   testing and hardening begins, so we recommend GA or later for
>   production if you are interested in using EAP.

This is also confirmed by entry in [JBoss FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20150323081629/http://jbossas.jboss.org/faq), saying

> Q: If EAP 6.1.0.Alpha is the same as community 7.2.0.Final, why is it
>   called Alpha? A: EAP has a much more conservative and rigid release
>   hardening process, including extensive quality testing and partner
>   certification. Historically every EAP release starts from our most
>   recent community final, and then releases in stages as this hardening
>   work is performed. The first EAP stage Alpha is of equivalent, or
>   better, quality to a community Final release.
>
> Q. Are there any restrictions on how I can use EAP 6.1.0 Alpha? A. No
>   – it has the same license and terms as AS releases however as it's an
>   Alpha release we don't recommend using it in production.

And these two redhat knowledgebase articles confirming that EAP 6.3.Alpha is also available for all to run in production (only visible for paid subscribers):

- ["Red Hat JBoss EAP 6.3 Alpha Availability"](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/762773)
- ["Using JBoss EAP alpha version in production without support subscription"](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1331263)

Edit: and now John Doyle, [Senior Manager responsible for Red Hat JBoss EAP 6](http://www.redhat.com/summit/speakers/session.html), [confirmed](https://developer.jboss.org/message/936151#936151) that

> The earlier statements about EAP 6.1 Alpha apply to all EAP 6 Alpha
>   releases.  They can be run in production.

**3. Self-compiled versions**

EAPs are also available as source distributions, and if you compile them yourself, removing any Red Hat trademarks, it should be legal to run them in production. Of course, you are completely on your own on supporting them. To make compiling easier, there is a script on [this github account](https://github.com/hasalex/eap-build), and using that script building your own EAP is as easy as

```
git clone git://github.com/hasalex/eap-build.git
cd eap-build
./build-eap.sh
```

See the project readme for details. There's also extended discussion on [one of its issues](https://github.com/hasalex/eap-build/issues/41) about the legal status of the build, which refers to [statement by Jason Greene](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/197780?start=75&tstart=0#jive-22575526718439150544), WildFly project lead, saying one of the ways to legally use the product is

> 3. Self build and support EAP - You get some of the benefits of the enterprise releases (e.g. patches to older major versions and so on),
>      but you have to invest time and energy to build and maintain/verify
>      your app server distribution bits.

Comment: We've shutdown jbossas.jboss.org because of the confusion that it adds. You'll now see a "we've moved page" and a notice that JBoss AS has been renamed to Wildfly and JBoss AS are not maintained.

Comment: @AlbertT.Wong IMO The confusion stems from the confusing policies of Red Hat and deleting the (old) site won't help that, though I agree keeping it online has created some confusion in itself. However, my answer should be correct anyways.

Comment: also, where is the FAQ now?

Comment: I've changed the FAQ link to point to archived version of the page for the time being, since cannot find the equivalent.

Comment: The link you reference was taken down because it is not the official position of the JBoss AS/Wildfly community.   We didn't want the incorrect information out on the internet.   There is no planned update to that FAQ.   If there is an update or question on position, current customers can reach out to Red Hat support.

Comment: @AlbertT.Wong I am referencing the answer of senior manager responsible for EAP, John Doyle. He just confirmed there was nothing incorrect about the information on jboss faq.

Comment: Also Jason Green, Wildfly project lead, has confirmed this information. I don't see why you keep on spreading the misinformation.

Comment: I'd be happy to talk to John and Jason.  Can you forward me the confirmation (email to albert@redhat.com)?   In the meantime, the FAQ you link does not exist anymore.    Please don't link it.

Comment: @AlbertT.Wong the confirmations were linked in my answer, but here they are: [Jason Greene](https://developer.jboss.org/message/819862): "This development restriction, however, does not apply to EAP alpha releases. EAP alpha releases may be ran in production if you so desire. As to their quality, 6.1.0.Alpha is of equivalent quality to a community final release.", [John Doyle](https://developer.jboss.org/message/936151#936151): "The earlier statements about EAP 6.1 Alpha apply to all EAP 6 Alpha releases.  They can be run in production."

Comment: @AlbertT.Wong was this clarified?

Comment: I am in the process of creating more official documentation on redhat.com to address this topic.

Comment: @AlbertT.Wong I guess nothing ever came out of that?

Comment: Is this information still valid that we cannot use jboss eap 7.2 binaries directly in production?

Comment: @JackSparrow information presented in the answer should still be valid, but it doesn't say that you cannot use - it says that in two cases you are allowed to use, allowed if you use alpha build or if you use self-compiled version (or if you buy the subscription, naturally)

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is: sort of.  You can obtain the binary version of the latest JBoss EAP 6.1.0.Alpha if you agree to a $0 developer license and agree to use it only for development purposes.  You do not get patches or support, however.

Also, it's open sourced under the LGPL in which case you don't have to agree to anything beyond the LGPL.  But then the trick is getting the source.  And you won't be getting the patched source.  An important consideration here is that the binary package is configured carefully (e.g. with respect to security defaults) whereas you're on your own if you compile it from available source.

Bottom line: buy a license if you are using it for any important commercial purpose so as not to be at some arbitrary fixed point in the source's evolution.

Comment: Alpha versions are free to use for everyone, same as 7.1.1.Final for example, just name is different, EAP 6.1.0.Alpha is same as 7.2.0.Final tag that you can find in git repo. $0 subscription applies to all non alpha binary releases.

Comment: Extract from JBoss FAQ : ``Q. Can I run the Alpha binaries in a production environment?
A.  Yes, Alpha releases may be run in any environment.``

Comment: Here is a link to the developer license:
http://www.jboss.org/developer-program/termsandconditions

Comment: @GuillaumeHusta Please link where you saw this. If it is http://jbossas.jboss.org/faq, please note that JBoss AS 7 is not EAP.  Those are two different products from Red Hat.   JBoss AS 7 is community and JBoss EAP 6 is the enterprise version.

Comment: @ctomc Red Hatter here.  They are not the same.  Jboss AS 7 is the community version and EAP is the enterprise.   AS 7 has no support and not developed anymore.   EAP is still in maintenance under Red Hat subscription.

Comment: @albert-t-wong Please see my comment in the question. The link was http://jbossas.jboss.org/faq, it was talking mainly about AS 7.2 and EAP 6.1 alpha. It's still interesting to read.

Comment: @GuillaumeHusta We've shutdown jbossas.jboss.org because of the confusion that it adds. You'll now see a "we've moved page" and a notice that JBoss AS has been renamed to Wildfly and JBoss AS are not maintained.

Comment: seems the source code for patch is available https://imgur.com/a/ckRELbS . Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Red Hatter here.   If you use JBOSS binaries, they are Red Hat Intellectual Property. You have to have a Red Hat subscription to use the software which may be $0 cost (developer use only) or more depending on what are your needs and/or subscription compliance (non-developer use like non-production or production).

Please see http://www.jboss.org/terms-and-conditions/ for the details.

Comment: this directly contradicts the FAQ (as well as comment by ctomc, among other things), which says alpha binaries can be run in production without costs.

Comment: Please see http://www.jboss.org/terms-and-conditions/ for the developer license.  You can't use any binaries in production without a subscription.  I think you might be confusing Wildfly with JBoss EAP.  Wildfly doesn't have this restriction.

Comment: @eis Please see updates.   Lots of incorrect knowledge being spread.   Also community releases (Wildfly and JBoss AS 7) and enterprise releases have different terms and conditions.

Comment: @albert-t-wong, I agree lot of incorrect knowledge is being spread, but I think you're doing the spreading right now and you really need to check your facts. Please note that [FAQ](http://jbossas.jboss.org/faq) is explicitly speaking about EAP 6.1.0 Alpha.

Comment: @albert-t-wong you can also check the answer from Jaikiran Pai [here](https://developer.jboss.org/message/819862#819862): "The 6.1 Alpha binary is made available for free (both for development **and production use**) to the entire community.". If you're from Red Hat, you should know who Jaikiran Pai or ctomc (Tomaz Cerar) are.

Comment: For a longer discussion, you can also check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995281/jboss-7-x-or-jboss-eap-6-x/17998315#17998315) and its associated links, which discuss the matter in length.

Comment: Added an answer now to this thread, since existing answers seem to be either wrong or misleading.

Comment: @eis We've shutdown http://jbossas.jboss.org/ because of the confusion that it adds.  You'll now see a "we've moved page" and a notice that JBoss AS has been renamed to Wildfly and JBoss AS are not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to original question "Can I use JBoss EAP 6 without a support license?":

According to official "Subscription Guide for Red Hat JBoss Middleware" dated Sept. 2015 (https://www.redhat.com/en/resources/subscription-guide-red-hat-jboss-middleware) you are allowed to use JBoss EAP 6 without support license only in following cases:

a) Environments only used by one person like a developer, testcase developer, architect

b) Developer desktops/ laptops or

c) Single-user development instances on a server (physical or virtual)

So you have to pay subscription for Test/QA and Production environments.

PS: price for support licence for "EAP Platform" is mentioned in comparison calculator - https://www.redhat.com/en/eap-calculator

PS2: There is a project with scripts custom building of JBoss EAP - https://github.com/hasalex/eap-build