# Error deploying war into JBoss AS 7 (domain mode): "Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment"

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x

I'm trying to deploy my war into JBoss AS 7 in domain mode, and I'm getting this error:

```
[Server:node02] 13:51:46,049 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "ROOT.war"
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
[Server:node02]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
[Server:node02]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
[Server:node02]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_30]
[Server:node02] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given parent is not an ancestor of this virtual file
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:116) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:122) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.getPathNameRelativeTo(VirtualFile.java:110) [jboss-vfs-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestClassPathProcessor.createAdditionalModule(ManifestClassPathProcessor.java:193) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestClassPathProcessor.handlingExistingClassPathEntry(ManifestClassPathProcessor.java:185) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.ManifestClassPathProcessor.deploy(ManifestClassPathProcessor.java:162) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
[Server:node02]         at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
[Server:node02]         ... 5 more
[Server:node02]
[Server:node02] 13:51:46,060 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (host-controller-connection-threads - 3) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ROOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"ROOT.war\".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"ROOT.war\""}}
[Server:node02] 13:51:46,062 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-9) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ROOT.war in 1ms
[Server:node02] 13:51:46,063 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (host-controller-connection-threads - 3) JBAS014774: Service status report
[Server:node02] JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ROOT.war".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "ROOT.war"
[Server:node02]
```

My jboss-deployment-structure.xml is bellow

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
<!--            <module name="org.hibernate" /> -->
        </exclusions>
        <!-- This allows you to define additional dependencies, it is the same 
            as using the Dependencies: manifest attribute -->
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.sun.jdk" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
    <!-- This is a module that re-exports the containers version of javassist.util.proxy -->
    <!-- This means that there is only one version of the Proxy classes defined -->
    <module name="deployment.sun.jdk">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="sun.jdk">
                <imports>
                    <include path="com/sun/crypto" />
                    <include path="com/sun/crypto/provider" />
                    <include path="com/sun/image/codec/jpeg" />
                    <include path="com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver" />
                    <include path="com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/tools" />
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </module>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: which version of jboss? [this](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3142) was fixed on 7.1.2.

Comment: I'm using jboss 7.1.1-Final but I'll try with this new version.. thanks..

Comment: there is not 7.1.2 at downloads page.. are you sure this version was released?

Comment: see my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995281/jboss-7-x-or-jboss-eap-6-x/17998315#17998315) - basically it is released as EAP 6.1 Alpha.

Comment: @eis EAP 6.1-ALPHA is again another version of AS, namely AS 7.2.0. AS 7.1.2 is an early tag for EAP 6.0 (it's hard to follow and remember really)

Comment: @ArjanTijms yes, I know - but the bug fixes were released as that version, there are no versions in between with that licensing released.

Comment: @eis there was an AS 7.1.3 that became EAP 6.0.1 and for a time there was an AS 7.1.4 that would have become EAP 6.0.2 but was canned. Then AS 7.2.0 became EAP 6.1-ALPHA, AS 7.2.0-something became EAP 6.1-BETA, then AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8 became EAP 6.1.0.GA, and now a mythical (invisible/hidden) AS 7.2.1 has become EAP 6.1.1, which is at the time of writing the latest stable version.

Comment: @eis >`with that licensing released` - If I'm not mistaken the license is ALWAYS LGPL. Red Hat can't change that (can't dual license ).

Comment: @ArjanTijms ah, you're right. licensing is always LGPL, however terms & agreement are different.

Comment: @eis Has to be the last comment here ;) But, indeed it's always LGPL. The difference is that when you download EAP (except the ALPHA) you enter into a *subscription*. The subscription has those terms you mention.

Comment: @ArjanTijms are these subscriptions really valid in terms of law?

Comment: @thiagoh I assume they are, but IANAL. If there was a stackexchange for law matters you should ask there (or consult your own lawyer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug in JBOSS AS version 7.1.1-Final, and it's fixed in newer versions.

As the good arcticle [The curious case of JBoss AS 7.1.2 and 7.1.3](http://henk53.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/the-curious-case-of-jboss-as-7-1-2-and-7-1-3/) explains JBoss AS 7.1.1 is full of bugs.

So I've built JBoss 7.2.0 from the source and this error no longer occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this issue with EAP 6.1 and JBoss Developer Studio 6.0.  I had moved from using EAP Server 6.0 to 6.1.  The fix was to remove *all* instances of the *.war file in question from my machine, then do a Full Publish of the .war project after restarting the new EAP 6.1 Runtime Server.

Answer (score 0):

I also facing same issue when upgrading my app from jboss5 to jboss-as-7.1.1 and After full day research changing the version to jboss-as-7.1.3.Final solved my problem.
`jboss-as-7.1.3.Final` is not directly downloadable, Developer have to build it himself, [building-jboss-as-7.1.3.Final](http://blog.kaltepoth.de/posts/2013/02/12/building-jboss-as7.html) shows complete process of building jboss-as-7.1.3.Final.

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I also facing the same issue, solve it after changing the java jdk version 1.6 to 1.7.