# JBoss AS 7.2 and 7.1.1 differences

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, redhat

For some reason JBoss AS 7.2 is not available for download (a question in itself). But what are the changes between AS 7.2 and 7.1.1? If we test on 7.1.1, what are the risks that the build will not work on 7.2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JBoss AS 7.2 is available for download, as I listed in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995281/jboss-7-x-or-jboss-eap-6-x/17998315#17998315), as [EAP 6.1 Alpha](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads) branding or [openlogic build](http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/jboss).

Issues fixed are listed [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7/fixforversion/12318469#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aversion-issues-panel). There are mainly bug fixes and some updates. Depends on what you do with your app, but I can't think of any big reason why a build working on 7.1.1 would not work on 7.2 (or 7.3 for that matter), other than relying on some specific client implementation version on some integrated component (hornetq comes to mind).