# JBOSS Server and Pricing

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am new to JBoss products. I found lot products under JBoss for web development. product that i found is JBOSS web, JBOSS WebServer, JBOSS Native, JBOSS AS, JBOSS EAP, and Community versions. what is the difference between these products and which one is allowed in commercial products for free. I do searched google, but i am confused with these products.

Answer (score 1):

If you look for a Java EE server, take a closer look on following:

### [Wildfly](http://wildfly.org/)

- community developed version of the application server
- former name was JBoss AS
- **Java EE 7** compliant
- You can use it in commercial products.

### [JBoss AS7](http://jbossas.jboss.org/)

- predecessor of the Wildfly
- **Java EE 6** compliant
- The last released version is 7.1.1, but you can get [sources of 7.2.0](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/tree/7.2.0.Final) and build it yourself.
- You can use it in commercial products.

### [JBoss EAP 6](http://www.redhat.com/products/jbossenterprisemiddleware/application-platform/)

- Red Hat supported version of the application server
- code is based on the JBoss AS7
- **Java EE 6** compliant
- users have to pay subscription to use it (They can get some versions freely for development purposes.)

Comment: IS Wildfly is alpha versions of JBOSS EAP like AS7 is alpha versions of EAP...?

Comment: Usually the community version is a base for EAP product. But there is no EAP version (yet) based on WildFly. I would not call community projects as "alpha versions". They have their own release cycle with alphas, betas, and finals.

Comment: Thanks you. but I found AS final versions are alpha versions of EAP in jboss site and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995281/jboss-7-x-or-jboss-eap-6-x). some other source said like you. I am confused.