# Does JBoss EAP 6.3.0 GA have a JBoss AS (community-edition) equivalent?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, wildfly, wildfly-8

From [this other SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995281/jboss-7-x-or-jboss-eap-6-x) it is evident that JBoss EAP 6.1.0 is based on JBoss AS 7.2.0! From the JBoss Github account it appears that JBoss AS 7.2.0 was the final community release (available in source-form under LGPL). However, I do not find any JBoss AS 7.3.0 or newer release on which the newer versions of JBoss EAP s.a. 6.2.0 and 6.3.0 are based. I do find however that JBoss AS 8 is now renamed as Wildfly, but not at all clear, if that happens to be the basis of say JBoss EAP 6.3.0.

Can anyone clarify ? Is it that RedHat/JBoss have ceased to release software which could be used to build equivalent binary, even if run without support ? While I won't be surprised, because that makes perfect commercial sense, but just wanted to be sure that I am not missing anything here.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401873/can-i-use-jboss-eap-6-without-a-support-license?lq=1) deals with much of the same issues discussed in this thread, but I don't want to duplicate content from there into this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EAP code repository was **forked/rebased** from AS7 after 7.2.0 tag.

And as such has its own lifecycle and has diverted considerably from **AS7/WildFly** (upstream) repository.

In short there is no such thing as JBoss 7.3 or 7.4 as it is internal version.

Code for all EAP releases is available on ftp and you can always build it yourself and use without restrictions (ftp://ftp.redhat.com/redhat/jbeap/).

You can see component details in https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673

In short, there is no a community version that corresponds to EAP 6.2 or 6.3 where you can download the binaries

Comment: Thanks Federico. Reading around online, I get the impression that it is quite challenging to build the JBoss EAP from sources, and that you need to remove all 'RedHat trademarks' from it, but not clear as to what exactly it means.

Comment: @icarus74 I think it's a little more complicated than just removing the RedHat brand. From my point the EULA prevents redistribution of the Red Hat trademarks (logos etc.), so neither of those licenses restrict your use of JBoss EAP within your own organisation. I think if you do want to run EAP binaries in production the best option is buy a subscription o in another case use Wildfly. See https://developer.jboss.org/thread/228319?start=0&tstart=0 and https://developer.jboss.org/thread/228640?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @icarus74 it's not that hard using the build script from github - I haven't had any problems doing so.